# Attempting to retrieve binary secret value: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: amazon-web-services, compression, aws-secrets-manager

I have a token file that is way too long to retrieve the contents from SecretsManager, so I am compressing the file and storing the bytes in SecretsManager. I then am trying to retrieve the secret value so I can use the token in my application. The secret value is the bytes from the file. I'm running into this error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Looking to see how I can fix this error and retrieve the secret value.

```
#declare tar file name
tar = "token.cache.tar.gz"
file = tarfile.open(tar,"w:gz")
file.add("token.cache")
file.close()

# store cache in aws secrets manager
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
with open("token.cache.tar.gz", "rb") as bts:
     response = client.create_secret(
         Name = 'ms-graph-binary',
         SecretBinary = bts.read()
 )

response = client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId='ac-demo-ms-graph-binary'
) ['SecretBinary'] 
with tarfile.open(fileobj=response.decode('utf-8'), mode='r') as cf:
    cf.extractall("token.cache.decompressed")
```

Edit: Ended up fixing the code and this is what I used to retrieve the secret.

```
import tarfile
import io
import boto3

client=boto3.client('secretsmanager')
with tarfile.open('token.cache.tar.gz', "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add('token.cache')
bts = open('token.cache.tar.gz','rb').read()

print("Length before",len(bts))

sec=client.update_secret(SecretId="ac-demo-ms-graph", SecretBinary=bts)

sec=client.get_secret_value(SecretId="ac-demo-ms-graph")['SecretBinary']

print("Length after",len(sec))

with tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(sec), mode='r:gz') as t:

    d=t.extractfile('token.cache')

    #print file content

    print("File content",str(d.read()))
```

Comment: when you add the secret to SecretsManager AWS spits out code snippets for you to do that also accessible after creation when you click on the secret resource in console. Why not use those?

Comment: When I run the provided snippet from AWS I just get "None" when I try to print get_secret(). I changed my code and got it to retrieve the secret value. I've edited my post to include the new code.

Comment: Try base64 decode `sec` _before_ passing it to `fileobj=io.BytesIO(sec)`. Checking the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html), `get_secret_value` will return base64 encoded bytes. "if the secret value was originally provided as binary data in the form of a byte array. The response parameter represents the binary data as a base64-encoded string." Tar will expect a magic byte, which is base64 encoded right now.